# How to find an open function which is not continous?

Tags: real-analysis

So i know that an open function is a function with the property that it sends an open interval to an open interval , but how to find a function which is open and not continous ?

Any hints ?

thanks

Comment: In $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology?

Comment: Do you know how to construct a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ which takes all real values in every interval?

Comment: yes in R with usual toplogy

Answer (score 1):

How about the function $f(z) = \arg z$ mapping from $S_1\subseteq \mathbb C$ to $[0,2\pi)$? An image of every open set is open, but $f$ is not continuous around $1$.